# Artists like (the late Pakistani singer) Nusrat Fateh Ali Kahn

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists, indian-classical

What genre would describe [the music of Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRUQ1nmZerk) (the late Pakistani superstar singer) and who are the current top singers who authentically embody that same style?

Comment: His roots are in the Sufi Qawwali: https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&hs=mxn&ei=7hzpW5PjGK-u0PEP0tSPgAc&q=Qawwali+singers&oq=Qawwali+singers&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0l9.4749.4898.0.5159.2.2.0.0.0.0.102.188.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.186....0.hqQAOgluJcw

You could also try: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5Plm8bBlBd7wXjZN2zdb8Fm/a-beginners-guide-to-qawwali-music

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@wcullen says in the comments](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7367/artists-like-the-late-pakistani-singer-nusrat-fateh-ali-kahn#comment10100_7367), Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan performs *qawwalis* in the Sufi tradition. The [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/qawwali) has a reasonable article on *qawwalis*, although the description of the style of music is given from the perspective of Western classical music.

Nusrat's nephew [Rahat Fateh Ali Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahat_Fateh_Ali_Khan) continues the tradition of performing *qawwalis*, in addition to singing *ghazals* and performing as a playback singer in several movie industries. The [Sabri brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabri_Brothers) are another troupe who are of the highest caliber. You could take a look at the music of the [Wadali brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadali_Brothers) and the [Bandanwazi Qawwal troupe](http://www.qawwal.in/index.html) as well. It seems they too come from very strong Sufi *qawwali* traditions. Also, [Wikipedia has a partial list of *qawwali* performers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sufi_singers#Qawwali), so you could search there for similar contemporary artists.